# Rendering problems Unity3D with some android phones

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, character, rendering, shapes

I don't know why some materials or shapes of my character are being poorly rendered in some Android phones. At first, I thought it had something to do with the GPU processor or the ram capacity or even the Android version. However, I ran it in 10-12 phones with similar properties and the results in some are like this:

[image]

When they are supposed to look like this:

[image]

As I said before it runs smoothly in an Android 4.4 with 1 GB Ram and standard GPU. However, a Samsung Galaxy S6 is not capable of rendering the character.
How is it possible, what should I change in unity or in its model to fix it?
Here is another screenshot of the model import properties:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try:
Some Android phones work better with OpenGL ES. Android phones also play well with ILCPP so try that. Use the light weight render pipeline.